# Прикрепить файл к письму, используя libcurl

Tags: c++, email, curl

Необходимо написать программу на C++, используя библиотеку libcurl, которая будет выполнять рассылку писем с некоторым текстом  и прикреплённым PDF-файлом. С текстом разобрался (есть неплохие примеры), а вот технологию прикрепления файлов не победил.

Ясно, что нужно как-то построить заголовки.

```
From: <ivanov@mail.ru>
To:  <petrov@mail.ru> 
Subject: Sample message
Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf8

Message text

Content-type: application/pdf

?????
```

Но что писать вместо знаков вопроса, и туда ли вообще надо это писать - вопрос. Подскажите, как должна выглядеть структура сообщения.

Comment: Для простоты - возьмите любое письмо со вложением и посмотрите, как это сделано.

Comment: Как это проще всего сделать?

Comment: Да сохраните письмо в файл и посмотрите внутрь...

Comment: Благодарю) Я даже и не знал о такой возможности)